# VB.Net how to use .FindAll in a List(of ) object?

Tags: .net, list, generics, delegates

I've tried to use .Find() methode and was successfully. But I can not understand how to work with FindAll to receive all items matching on a "flexible" keyword (in my case this keywords is called ClassGuid).

```
Public Class clsFindConnection
Private Delegate Function ConMatchDelegate(ByVal con As PropertyConnection, ByVal ClassGuid As String) As Boolean



    Public Function GetPropertyConnectionsByGuid(ByVal ClassGuid As String, ByVal LBaseConnections As List(Of PropertyConnection)) As List(Of PropertyConnection)
        Dim Res As List(Of PropertyConnection)
        Dim dl As New ConMatchDelegate(AddressOf ConnectionFromMatch)
        Res = LBaseConnections.FindAll(dl)'<-- ERROR. Can not work because delegate is only using a single item. 
        Return Res
    End Function

    Friend Function ConnectionFromMatch(ByVal con As PropertyConnection, ByVal ClassGuid As String) As Boolean
        If con.PaintPluginFrom Is Nothing Then Return False
        If con.PaintPluginFrom.Plugin Is Nothing Then Return False
        If con.PaintPluginFrom.Plugin.Guid = ClassGuid Then Return True
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

How can this be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda expression to pass the second parameter:

```
Res = LBaseConnections.FindAll(Function(con) ConnectionFromMatch(con, ClassGuid))
```

---

EDIT to answer your comment:

`FindAll` takes a `Predicate(Of T)` (`Predicate(Of PropertyConnection)` in your case), so you can't pass a `ConMatchDelegate` to it, since the signature is not compatible. So I create a `Predicate(Of PropertyConnection)` using an anonymous method. This will probably be more understandable:

```
Dim filter As Predicate(Of PropertyConnection) = Function(con) ConnectionFromMatch(con, ClassGuid)
Res = LBaseConnections.FindAll(filter)
```

Comment: Thanks. And it works like a charm. But I don't understand why. Is is possible to rewrite it with more description or with a delegate instead of lamnda expression or with some comments in your line?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I m a C# guy, but I hope we can share a concept here.

**FindAll** method of List class takes a **Predicate**. Predicate is a specialized delegate which takes a single parameter and returns a Boolean value. So, FindAll internally does iteration of each item in the list and which item meets the condition defined in predicate, will be included in result.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<PropertyConnection> lstConn = new List<PropertyConnection>(){ 
                                                   new PropertyConnection() { Id = 10}, 
                                                   new PropertyConnection() { Id = 20 }, 
                                                   new PropertyConnection() { Id = 30 } };

            List<PropertyConnection> filtered = lstConn.FindAll(MyDelegate);
           // so filtered contains just one item with Id = 30 
        }

        private static bool MyDelegate(PropertyConnection con) // your own delegate
        {
            if (con.Id > 20)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public class PropertyConnection // sample class
    {
        public int Id;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Santoo. I see still the same problem. How to submit a "variable" to MyDelegate? Thomas Levesque already answered with a lambda expression solution which works. But there I do not fully understand why. Thanks for your help.